# JAXB @XmlElement in comment

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to put in comment a XmlElement.

I have a XmlType:

```
@XmlType(name = "Person")
```

With somes XmlElements:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(name = "MiddleName", required = false)
protected String middleName;
@XmlElement(name = "Surname", required = true)
protected String surname;
@XmlElement(name = "UserReference", required = true)
protected String userReference;
```

I would like to put in comment the not required element.

Desire output:

```
<Person>
    <Name>Anthony</Name>
    <!--MiddleName>Jack</MiddleName-->
    <Surname>Smith</Surname>
    <UserReference>741098871125866</UserReference>
</Person>
```

Someone knows if there is a property or something like that to say JAXB to write the XmlElement as a comment?

Comment: And what about adding a comment before the <Surname> XmlElement?    
<!-- message 1 --> <Surname>
That will solve my problem.

Comment: I've been reading about Marshaller.Listener, but I just wanna put some comments before one XmlElement...

Comment: You can't add comments or processing instructions with pure JAXB. You'll need some XML postprocessing afterwards, for instance an XSLT or DOM/SAX/StAX manipulation.